# running older simulator versions in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, osx-mountain-lion

I have upgraded my mac mini to mountain lion 10.8 version. and XCode to 4.5
But now I am not seeing simulator versions other than ios6. However I want to run application on multiple platforms. How should I do that? Because when I am trying to download simulator versions from XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads, I am seeing "No components available".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add older version of iOS SDK in Xcode 4.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523888/how-can-i-add-older-version-of-ios-sdk-in-xcode-4-5)