# iOS 4 Simulator with Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: ios, simulator

I am building an application in Xcode 4.5.2 and I want to test it on iOS 4 but it seems that the copy-paste method is not working. I tried everything and nothing seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by copy/paste method? Where are you pasting?
Are you testing on a device, or just the simulator?

Comment: By coppying i mean the methods i see here or similar posts  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523888/how-can-i-add-older-version-of-ios-sdk-in-xcode-4-5

Comment: So you want older version of ios simulator right?

Comment: Yea, i only have 5 and 6, but i must have 4. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, If you want iOS 4 simulator than you have to install its SDK. Which you can download using xcode. select Xcode from upper ToolBar > Preference > Downloads > Components > here you can see all the old and new simulator download ios 4 simulator and it will autometically added to your xcode.
[Here](http://i45.tinypic.com/2uhb88m.png) it is.

Yes you have to set diployment target to ios 4 in your project target to use ios 4 simulator.

Happy coding.

Comment: No, the iOS4 does not appear there, at least for me,btw i am working on a   10.8.2 mac.

Comment: I am working in Xcode 4.6 and mac 10.7.5 , and i can see their ios 4.3, ios5,ios5.1 and ios 6 simulator. are you sure you have navigate right at that path?

Comment: Yea well, as i have read, it sais that they don't support ios 4 on lion...

Comment: ohh, sorry then i dont know that .can you give me that link just for my information,coz i am thinking to upgrade my os

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651773/install-simulator-sdk-4-3-to-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion/11743817#11743817