# Develop app for iOS 3.1.3 on Mac OS X 10.11?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have a Mac with OS X 10.11 and Xcode 7.2. I also have an ancient iPod Touch first generation with iOS 3.1.3.

I'd like to create, upload and run an app of my own on this device, but Xcode does not let me ("Unsupported OS version").

I downloaded and tried older Xcode versions, but everything before version 6 refuses to start on OSX 10.11 and 6 has the same problem.

Is it at all possible to do this, and if so, how? If not, whats are the latest OSX/Xcode versions that work with 3.1.3?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: You may want to test one of the methods from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523888/how-can-i-add-older-version-of-ios-sdk-in-xcode-4-5). Not sure if they work on one of the newer XCode versions though.

Comment: Unfortunately you need an older version of Mac OS X. I have a 1st gen iPod touch myself and you have to wonder if it's truly worth the effort you're going through to get an app on it  ;) The latest Xcode will run code compatible with iOS 4.3 though, so a second gen is possible ish.