# Where to download an slightly older iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

Installing OSX from scratch with XCode 7.2 gives me iOS SDK 9.2.

I need iOS SDK 9.0 for some compatibility issues. Is there any download page for that?

I visited https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/ which only contains download links to iOS 9.2 and iOS 9.3beta right now.

[image]

Comment: If you want to run your code on simulator with older iOs you can add this version in Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The previous versions of SDK are bundled with each version of Xcode, which you can download from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?name=Xcode. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13061104/5806210 on how to add older SDKs. Also you can install other versions of simulators.

Answer (score 8):

You can download and install "older" simulator versions the following way:

- Start Xcode -> Window -> Devices
  [image]
- Choose to "Add Simulator" in the bottom left
  [image]
- Click on "iOS version" and choose "Download more simulators"
  [image]
- Choose the ones you want
  [image]

Comment: Isn't a Simulator something else than an SDK entirely?

Comment: Downloading Simulator is not the same as downloading SDK. Question is about downloading SDK.

Comment: @VladimirIgnatyev answers questions raised by your response

Comment: Boom. Might not have answered the question, but did the trick in replicating behavior seen on an older version of iOS

Comment: it works for me thank's ;)

Comment: This is not the relevant answer. SDKs and simulators are different. Question points towards SDK.

Comment: @iSeeker see the first two comments, this has already been raised repeatedly and I will continue to ignore that claim since the answer is obviously helpful for some people, even if not helpful to you and others. Fun fact underscoring that: I got more upvotes (and reputation) on this answer than the accepted one.