# Is there any way to downgrade Xcode project from 8 to 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode8

I developed task using Xcode v8. But now I need to be able to open it in Xcode v7.
I have needed version of Xcode. But I cannot open Files and perform build.

[image: I cannot open Files and perform build]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to download an slightly older iOS SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876144/where-to-download-an-slightly-older-ios-sdk)

Comment: @Sneak while I'm not sure what the OP is asking, I think they have the older versions of Xcode and are just having issues building an Xcode 8 project on Xcode 7.  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42583702/2415822).

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked before though, let me try to find a different dupe target.

Comment: @JAL Yeah your right, he added the picture and more info later it seems. I think I misunderstood his actual question.

Comment: @JAL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851459/the-document-main-storyboard-requires-xcode-8-0-or-later Here is the duplicate and solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xcode 7 but you will need to change all the syntax manually. There is no converter available for downgrading.

If your code is completely in Obj-C then it will not be a problem for you, but for swift you will end up with a lot of changes.

If you want to test your functionality you can download lower version simulators and add device with that OS.

Comment: Yes, code in Obj-C. But there are XIBs which are in new format

Comment: @АндрейАссаул I don't think XIB's would be a pain

Comment: I just cannot open them. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVL50.png) Need to perform changes in XML. And I'm not sure, that these changes are correct